# Инлайт кнопки не хотят работать

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Кусочек кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        markup= types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        cnop1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="RU", callback_data='rus')
        cnop2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="EN", callback_data='eng')
        markup.add(cnop1, cnop2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "На каком языке мне разговаривать?", 
            reply_markup=markup)
    
@bot.add_callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def ansfer(call):
    if call.data == 'rus':
```

(Дальше идет сам код википедии который без ошибок работает если отдельно)

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: TeleBot.add_callback_query_handler() got an unexpected keyword argument'func'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обработки `callback` используется декоратор [callback_query_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#callback-query-handler):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
```

А [add_callback_query_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e55fe962ca58aded97d676c7b36fa71519339c5c/telebot/__init__.py#L5934) вспомогательный метод бота для добавления обработчиков `callback`